# Fundamental Group of the Long Line

Tags: general-topology, ordinals, fundamental-groups

Let $\omega_1$ be the first uncountable ordinal. The long
line $L$ is defined as the cartesian product of the first
uncountable ordinal $ \omega _{1}$ with the half-open interval
$ [0,1)$  equipped with the order topology that arises from
the lexicographical order on
$\omega _{1} \times [0,1)$. That means that of we
set by $"<_L"$ the lexicographic order on
$\omega_1 \times [0,1)$ then the topology on
$\omega_1 \times [0,1)$ is generated by "interval" base

$$ ((k_1,a), (k_2,b))=\{(k,x) \in \omega_1 \times [0,1) \vert \ \vert  
(k_1,a) <_L (k,x) <_L (k_2,b)$$

My question is if it's true that the fundamental group $\pi(L,l_0)$ of the long
line is trivial (let $l_0$ is any base point) or what's the reason? Although it seems to be a rather
natural question I nowhere found a serious discussion about this problem. My
intuition says that it should be trivial, but I'm not not sure.

My idea: I have to show that any loop $f: S^1 \to L$ is contractible.
My idea is to observe that one can find a *finite* number of "neighboured"
$a_1, a_2,..., a_n \in \omega_1$ and show that the image
of $f$ is contained in $\bigcup_{i=1}^n {a_i} \times [0,1) \subset L$ and
then because of finiteness of $a_1, a_2,..., a_n \in \omega_1$ one sees that
$\bigcup_{i=1}^n \{a_i\} \times [0,1) \cong [0,1)$ and this space is contractible.

Is the argument ok? My worries are based on my doubts if that's make
sense to say that we can fetch some "neighboured" $a_1, a_2,..., a_n \in \omega_1$.
What should "neighboured" here mean? If we believe in continuum hypothesis
then $\omega_1= \mathbb{R}$ and it is strage to say what does it mean that
two elements $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$ a "neighboured". If $a \neq b$ there is always
some other element between them, therefore I doubt that my argument above should
work, or not?

note that we were done if we could show that every loop $f: S^1 \to L$  must be contained in a subset of the form $\{r\} \times [0,1) \subset L$. This one is clearly contractible, so the loop would be also contractible. Is it possible to do it that way around?

Does somebody see how can I argue to conclude that the fundamental
group of $L$ is trivial (if that's really the case)?

Comment: Seems like you should be able to get some mileage from knowing that the image of any loop is compact (because it's the continuous image of a compact set).

Comment: The continuum hypothesis just says that $\omega_1$ and $\mathbb{R}$ have the same *cardinality*.  Their orders are still totally different from each other though.

Comment: @EricWofsey: right. that was just an informal "hand weavy" attept how nearly one may try to image how $\omega_1$ might look like. of course different orders could make two sets of same cardinality not isomorphic

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The key to understanding questions like this about the long line is the following observation.

**Lemma**: For any $x\in L$, the interval $I_x=\{y\in L:y\leq x\}$ is order-isomorphic to $[0,1]$.

*Proof*: Let $A$ be the set of $y\in L$ such that $(0,0)<y<x$ and the second coordinate of $y$ is rational.  Then $A$ is countable (since the first coordinate of $x$ is a countable ordinal so there are only countably many choices for the first coordinate of $y$) and densely ordered without endpoints, so it is order-isomorphic to $(0,1)\cap\mathbb{Q}$.  Also, $A$ is dense in $I_x$ and $I_x$ is Dedekind-complete (and has endpoints), so $I_x$ is the Dedekind-completion of $A$ (including endpoints).  So, $I_x$ is order-isomorphic to the Dedekind completion (including endpoints) of $(0,1)\cap\mathbb{Q}$, which is just $[0,1]$. $\blacksquare$

This Lemma is really the reason that $L$ is called the "long *line*".  If you cut it off at any point before the end, it really does just look like the ordinary real line.  To see that it is different, you have to go all the way "uncountably far" to the end.

In particular, it follows that $I_x$ is homeomorphic to $[0,1]$ and contractible.  But any continuous map from a separable space to $L$ has image contained in $I_x$ for some $x\in L$ (take $x$ to be an upper bound for the image of a countable dense subspace).  So, any continuous map from a separable space to $L$ is nullhomotopic.  In particular, this implies all the homotopy groups of $L$ are trivial.

(Note that the Lemma also implies that the image of a loop in $L$ does *not* have to be covered by finitely many sets of the form $\{a\}\times[0,1)$.  Indeed, for any infinite ordinal $\alpha<\omega_1$, the interval $I_{(\alpha,0)}$ contains infinitely many sets of the form $\{a\}\times[0,1)$, but can be covered by a single loop since it is homeomorphic to $[0,1]$.)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it suffices to show that the image of any continuous map $f:S^1\rightarrow L$ is bounded, i.e., contained in $\alpha\times[0,1)$ for some countable $\alpha$, and then use that $\alpha\times[0,1)\simeq[0,1)$. This is because $L$ has the so-called $\omega$-compactness property: the closure of any countable set is compact, and also $S^1$ is separable (actually even compact as pointed out in the comment).

Comment: Your last argument I not understand: why $\omega$-compactness property of $L$ and separability of $S^1$ imply that the image $f(S_1)$ is contained in one $\alpha\times[0,1)$?

Comment: could you elaborate a bit more the chain of arguments of what you wrote in your last sentence?

Comment: @user7391733 It's well explained in Eric's answer. Just to clarify: $\alpha\times[0,1)$ and $\{\alpha\}\times[0,1)$ are different! $\alpha\times[0,1)$ is the first $\alpha$ many intervals, and $\{\alpha\}\times[0,1)$ is the $\alpha$-th interval. Eric's $I_x$ is just the initial segment consisting of everything up to $x$.

Comment: @user7391733 As Eric says you just take a countable dense subset $Y$ of $S^1$ (or actually any separable space), say $Y=\{y_1,y_2,y_3,...\}$. We have $f(S^1)=f(\overline{Y})\subseteq\overline{f(Y)}$ (a basic property of continuous maps). Since $f(Y)$ is countable, $\overline{f(Y)}$ is compact.

Comment: alright, so the point is really that *every* countable subset $C \subset L$ is contained in a set of the form $I_x=\{y\in L:y\leq x\}$ for $x \in L$. but
we also observe also that $I_x$ is closed in $L$ as closure of open set $\{y\in L:y < x\} \subset L$. Therefore $I_x$ contains the closure of $C$ and we are done as Eric shows above that $I_x$ is contractible.